# Sending indexPath.row from didselectRowAtIndexPath to prepareForSegue via sender

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, sender

I have seen many solutions however i cant get this right. I want to call prepareForSegue from the didSelectRowAtIndexPath function when a cell is tapped. Then i want to retrieve the row index that was tapped on, from inside the prepareForSegue function so i can use it to pass information to another view. I think i am calling the function correctly but there is something going wrong in my prepareForSegue function. I know its an easy solution i am just very stuck. Heres my current code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("notificationsToAnswers", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    //the below line is incorrect and should be something else
    let selectedIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
    //pass data on using the index
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? How is that line wrong?

Comment: selectedIndex always gets set to nil with the current code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("notificationsToAnswers", sender: indexPath)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "notificationsToAnswers" {
        //the below line is incorrect and should be something else
       let selectedIndexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath
       let index = selectedIndexPath.row
       //pass data on using the index
    }

}
```

Comment: Assuming i have a local array called results that stores my information. If i try to access it using results[selectedIndex], i get an error saying i cant use an NSIndex as an index for the array

Comment: So, I noticed that after swiping on a row, or after clicking on the edit button, thats when `indexPathForSelectedRow` starts returning null. can you please explain why this is so.    But, your solution was excellent.